# sql server update duplicate rows in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope i can explain my problem very well.
I have a table without a primary key. To get unique row i have to `select distinct (make, model, category,onhand)` together and the result is 2 rows for each one with onhand `is null` and the other onhand `is not null`.

Now what I want to do is update my table to `set null onhand  = onhand with value` for each duplicated row
I had this query to find the duplicates-2 for each

```
select  distinct MAKE, MODEL, category, PRGR,
CountDuplicateRows= COUNT(1)    --column to count the number of duplicates
from [OITM2]
WHERE PRGR !='p'
GROUP BY  MAKE, MODEL, category, PRGR
HAVING COUNT(1)>1   --more than one record
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC  --sort by most duplicates
```

But i can't figure out how to update the onhand `null`. i'm using sql server 2008 r2.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has the very nice feature of updatable CTEs and subqueries.  You can do:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by  MAKE, MODEL, category, PRGR) as cnt
      from oitm2
      where prgr <> 'p'
     )
update toupdate
    set onhand = YOURVALUEGOESHERE
    where cnt > 1 and onhand is null;
```

Notice that the subquery is not using aggregation, but instead using the `count()` window function.  This appends the count to each row of the original data -- and it can still be used for updating.

If you want to get an arbitrary value from the same group of rows, you can add that into `toupdate`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by  MAKE, MODEL, category, PRGR) as cnt,
             max(onhand) over (partition by  MAKE, MODEL, category, PRGR) as onhand_value
      from oitm2
      where prgr <> 'p'
     )
update toupdate
    set onhand = onhand_value
    where cnt > 1 and onhand is null;
```

Comment: thnx alot the second one what i need exactly!