# Change value of duplicated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a table with tow columns(`ID`, `Data`) and there are `3` rows with same value.

```
ID          Data
4           192.168.0.22 
4           192.168.0.22 
4           192.168.0.22
```

Now I want to change third row `DATA` column. In update SQL Server Generate an error that I ca not change the value.

I can delete all `3` rows. But I can not delete `third` row separately.

This table is for a software that I bought and I changed the `third Server IP`.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server update duplicate rows in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762096/sql-server-update-duplicate-rows-in-the-same-table)

Comment: the row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows(3rows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following query

```
create table #tblSimilarValues(id int, ipaddress varchar(20))
insert into #tblSimilarValues values (4, '192.168.0.22'),
(4, '192.168.0.22'),(4, '192.168.0.22')
```

Use Below query if you want to change all rows

```
with oldData as (
      select *,
             count(*) over (partition by id, ipaddress) as cnt
      from #tblSimilarValues
     )
update oldData
    set ipaddress = '192.168.0.22_1'
    where cnt > 1;
select * from #tblSimilarValues
```

Use Below query if you want to skip firs row

```
;with oldData as (
      select *,
             ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by id, ipaddress order by id, ipaddress) as cnt
      from #tblSimilarValues
     )
update oldData
    set ipaddress = '192.168.0.22_2'
    where cnt > 1;

select * from #tblSimilarValues
drop table #tblSimilarValues
```

You can find the live demo [**live demo here**](https://rextester.com/ZKUE89028)

Comment: You can use also >=, <= or = with cnt if you want to update only specific rows based on the requirements.

Comment: thank you very much. ROW_NUMBER () worked very well.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no column that allows us to distinguish these rows from each other, there's no "third row" (nor a first or second one for that matter).

We can use a `ROW_NUMBER` function to apply *arbitrary* row numbers to these rows, however, and if we place that in a CTE, we can apply `DELETE`/`UPDATE` actions via the CTE and use the arbitrary row numbers:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null, Data varchar(15))
insert into @t(ID,Data) values
(4,'192.168.0.22'),
(4,'192.168.0.22'),
(4,'192.168.0.22')

;With ArbitraryAssignments as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Data ORDER BY Data) as rn
    from @t
)
delete from ArbitraryAssignments where rn > 2

select * from @t
```

This produces two rows of output - one row was deleted.

Note that I say that the `ROW_NUMBER` is arbitrary. One of the expressions in both the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses is the same. By definition, then, we know that no real `ORDER` is defined by this (because all rows within the same partition, by definition, have the same value for that expression).

Answer (score 1):

In this case ID columns allows duplicate value ***which is wrong***, **ID** should be unique.
Now what you can do is create a **new column** make that `unique` or `Primary Key` or **change the duplicate values of ID** column and make it `Unique/Primary key`.

Now as per your `Unique key/Primary key` you can update **DATA** column value by query as below:

```
UPDATE <Table Name>
SET DATA = 'new data'
WHERE ID = 3;
```

Comment: @SurajKumar in this case ID will be **Unique** and SQL server will allow, see my answer first.